# Intersection of ideals corresponding to simplicial complexes at different points?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes, algebraic-graph-theory

Suppose I have two simplicial complexies $\triangle_1$ and $\triangle_2$. Consider  their [Stanley-Reisner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley%E2%80%93Reisner_ring) ideals $I(\triangle_1)$ and $I(\triangle_2)$. I want to get their intersections when they meet at one point and at two points.

**How can I express the two different intersections in terms of ideal operations?**

Comment: Could you make your question more precise? Presumably $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are simplicial complexes on the same vertex set, and you are interested in the cases where their intersection is a single vertex, or a pair of vertices. Is that correct?

Comment: @Mark Grant yes you understood correctly.